# UnZip Dissambler Pipeline

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

I have a requirement where I am receiving a Zip file at a receive location.
I want to unzip the zip file when I receive it.

How can this be achieved in Biztalk 2010?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the following topic. Where they unzip the files in a custom pipeline.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/152565/Unzip-Files-in-a-Custom-Pipeline-Component